# Primes satisfying $3^{d \cdot ord_p(2)+1} \equiv 2 \pmod{p}$ -- only 331?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I'm looking for primes $p$ that satisfy the integer equation

$3^{d \cdot ord_p(2)+1} \equiv 2 \pmod{p}$

am amazed that of the first 30k primes, only $p=331$ works (eg, with $d=4$):

$3^{4 \cdot 30 + 1} \equiv 2 \pmod{331}$

Are there methods or tools for trying to show that $p=331$ is in fact the only solution (or not)? Or does the chaotic nature of $ord_p(2)$ make this hopeless?

The equation is motivated by enforcing the coprimality of two periods, namely the period of $3^x-2^x \pmod{p}$ and the period of $2^k-1 \pmod{p}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me this feels like a lot of other problems (such as Wieferich primes) where there will probably be infinitely many solutions but they are very sparse.

You're asking whether $2\cdot 3^{-1}$ is in the multiplicative subgroup generated by $3^{\mathop{\rm ord}_p(2)}$ modulo $p$. The cardinality of that multiplicative subgroup is somewhere between $\frac{p-1}{\mathop{\rm ord}_p(2)}$ and $\frac{p-1}{\mathop{\rm ord}_p(2)} \frac{\mathop{\rm ord}_p(3)}{p-1}$. Typically this cardinality is small, but sometimes it will be quite large, which means that it's more likely that $2\cdot 3^{-1}$ will be in that subgroup.